# How to align divs perfectly for liquid layout?

Tags: html, css

In its simplest form, the problem is as follows. I have two divs (Ldiv and Rdiv) filling up my screen. Widths are 60% and 40% respectively, and heights vary according to the amount of content. Ldiv floats left and Rdiv floats right. The problem is that, as I narrow the window and push Rdiv against Ldiv, I seem to lose the right margin of Rdiv unless I make its width 35-39% instead of 40%. I have tried wrapping both inside an enclosing div container but this hasn't worked any better.

Can this be fixed by making one of the divs (say, Ldiv) a fixed width (in which case the layout is not entirely liquid, but that wouldn't matter too much)? I've read a number of posts here which say this is the way to go, but I can't see why it should. Many others say that with only 2 divs they should both float, but is there a non-floating alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Post a link to your code, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to give a real answer without seeing your code, BUT i guess to still have margins and paddings in your divs and/or your body element. So, in consequence the 40/60% dont add up to 100%. You can "remove" this with

```
body, #Ldiv, #Rdiv {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need padding and margins to make the interface attractive. This idea would work ok if I specified the absolute size, but how to make liquidity work with just percentages?

Comment: you could put another div into these divs. and give THEM margins. ;)